# Get KnowledgeBaseAnswerDialog while querying to Azure Knowledge Base

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-language-understanding, azure-cognitive-services

I am new to Azure Cognitive services. I have created an Azure functions(C#) which uses QuestionAnsweringClient.GetAnswers Method[text](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.ai.language.questionanswering.questionansweringclient.getanswers?view=azure-dotnet) to get the answers from Azure Knowledgebase
I would also need the List of prompts associated with the answer.

Can some one please help me on this issue ?

I referred [KnowledgeBaseAnswerDialog Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.ai.language.questionanswering.knowledgebaseanswercontext.previousquestion?view=azure-dotnet#azure-ai-language-questionanswering-knowledgebaseanswercontext-previousquestion) but could not find any solution.

Comment: Do you mean the configured follow up prompts?

Comment: @Skin Yes
I could get follow up prompts after referring to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.ai.language.questionanswering.knowledgebaseanswer.dialog?view=azure-dotnet